# Extension degree of a splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

I want to show:

> If $f(x) \in F[x]$ is a poly of degree n, then the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$ in $\bar F$  has an extension degree less or equal to $n!$.

I think $n!$ has something to do with permutation but I cannot proceed further.

Comment: Or, more elementarily, it as to do with the fact that the $k$-th time you add a root you further extend the field with degree at most $n-k+1$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli How simple! Thank you.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Why don't you add that as an answer?

Comment: @Arthur I'd rather look for a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Degree of a splitting field is no greater than $n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318587/degree-of-a-splitting-field-is-no-greater-than-n). See also [this similar proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763216/let-k-be-a-field-and-fx-in-kx-be-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-and-let-f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is separable: The Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(\overline F/F)$ acts faithfully on the roots of $f$ (because they generate $\overline F$). Hence it embeds in $S_n$. Because $f$ is separable, $|G|=[\overline F:F]$.

In general: if $\alpha_1, \ldots,\alpha_k$ are the roots of $f$, $k\leq n$, then each $\alpha_i$ has degree $\leq n-i+1$ over $F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{i-1})$. So the degree of $\overline F=F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k)$ is $\leq n\cdots (n-k+1)\leq n!$.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but I'm not familiar with faithful acting and stuff

Comment: What it means is that you can view the Galois group as a group of permutations of the roots of $f$. "Faithful" means a $\sigma\in G$ is determined by what it does with the roots.